# Pâtés raw from inside in another oven - how to make them right in this oven?

Tags: oven, pate

We used to do different pâtés in one oven, they are always great.
For Christmas we can use different oven and, so far, three pâtés were raw from inside.

Could you advice what configuration of oven to try to get it right?

Some more data:

- Pâtés - different vegetarian ones.
- Default oven that works great:  electric build-in Simens (similar to [this Simens](http://theappliancecompany.uk.com/article-pdfs/hb13ab550b.pdf)), in "3d hot air" mode 180C, middle height.
- Oven we can not master: electric free-standing Amica. So far we made three failed experiments

  - in 180C "hot air" mode - raw from inside
  - in "hot air" 200C mode it burned Pâté from outside and left inner part raw
  - "hot top+hot bottom" 200C, was better as not burned it from outside, but still Pâté was raw inside.

Any advice how to get it not raw from inside?

Comment: Any physical supporting explanation highly welcome.
I suspected current Amica oven to have smaller heat capacity resulting in much less transmission via radiation. AFAIUnderstand, heat transmission via radiation should go thought body and head from inside. That's why experiment with "hot+bottom heat" mode. However, thing was still raw from inside (but not burned from outside , that's progress...). Any clues how to make it work and why such difference between two ovens?

Comment: Just a thought: Did you check the actual oven temperature with an oven thermometer? And I mean in *both* ovens...

Comment: Your "line of experiments" sounds very reasonable. What would happen if you stick with 180°C / hot air, but baked a bit longer?